# Why Docker pull ubuntu not working Azure VM?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

Following is the scenario.

1. I have my local machine Windows 10.

   - I have installed Docker On Windows
   - Windows Container mode

     ```
     docker pull ubuntu  // successfull
     ```
2. I have one machine at Azure VM

   - I have installed same docker on windows over there.
   - Windows container mode

     ```
     C:\Users\user1>docker pull ubuntu
     Using default tag: latest
     latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
     no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
     ```

As requested Docker Info of Both Machine.
Just to add into above point I have enable experimental feature in both but still same result. Working on Local machine but not in Azure VM.
**Working Machine Configuration(My Local machine )**

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 27
Server Version: 18.09.0-ce-beta1
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
 Windows:
 LCOW:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 17134 (17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804)
Operating System: Windows 10 Enterprise Evaluation Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.286)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 7.91GiB
Name: DESKTOP-8G69CD1
ID: A27H:64IP:4SYL:UUR6:46WH:BC4P:HR2U:EAVL:3NDL:3Q44:GWGA:ZCMN
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2018-10-08T07:00:22.061086+05:30
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

**Non working configuration ( Azure VM)**

```
Containers: 0
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 0
Server Version: 18.09.0-ce-beta1
Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
 Windows:
 LCOW:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: ics l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
 Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 17134 (17134.1.amd64fre.rs4_release.180410-1804)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.285)
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 7GiB
Name: DockerVMWin10
ID: B7YP:NZON:KDGQ:M2XM:QNCY:ABCU:JJJ7:ZHLB:HSLE:TBHG:UDUI:666Q
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 26
 System Time: 2018-10-08T01:36:52.3309247Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Comment: Please include the output of `docker info` in each environment.

Comment: After change your local windows10 docker to `windows container mode`, have you reset your computer? This is not reasonable to run linux container on windows mode.

Comment: It is working for local machine but same configuration not working at azure vm